# Install SSL Cert on Windows 2016

Tags: windows, ssl, api

I have an on-premise Windows 2016 Server where I'm running my Web API as a service (IIS is not installed).

I have several files that I'm not sure what to do with.

server.cer
server.crt
server.p7b
server.pem
server.pfx

What do I need to do to make API connections secure when it's running as a Windows Service?

Answer (score 0):

These files contain a certificate, but
you can't do anything with it because you don't have the software to support HTTPS.
You will need IIS to truly support HTTPS.

The most you can do with Web API is get a certificate from the client,
then get information from the certificate, such as the issuer and subject.

Normally, you generate your own certificates for that, which you then distribute
to your clients so they can identify themselves to your server.
Each client will have his own identifying certificate (which they are not
supposed to communicate to others).

For more information see the Microsoft article
[Working with SSL in Web API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/working-with-ssl-in-web-api).